AWS Cognito Hosted UI vs Lambda Authorizer vs AWS Cognito Custom Flow
I am developing a new mobile Application.
For the purpose of User Authentication/Authorization, I created a user pool on AWS Cognito.
I will be integrating Social Provider Register/Login
The problem is: Cognito Hosted UI is very limited in terms of UI customization.

What are the pros and cons of using alternatives such as Lambda Authorizer ?

Is it possible to use Cognito Custom Auth Flow with my Custom UI ?



Did you check Amplify Authenticator component?

I am checking it now... Thanks for reference..
Just a question: Does Amplify Authenticator replace Hosted UI completely ?

Yes, its another option if you don't want to use Hosted UI.

There are no cons of using Lambda as an authorizer. It actually comes with a lot of pros. You can handle as per your custom requirements.
If you wanna proceed with custom auth challenge, you would need to integrate lambda for them as well. You will need 4 lambdas and will have to make use of SES/SNS.But, custom auth challenge is not so customizable. So, lambda authorizer is a better option for you.
Let me know if I've addressed your issue. It'll help me improve myself better. Thanks.

Lambda Authorizer seems more customizable
however, it introduces boilerplate code as I understand
I need to implement a flow like Authorozation_Code with PKCE by myself from scratch
Am I right ?

Yes, you've understood the right way!
